# Issue with Bundling and Minification of CSS after NuGet update (ASP MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, nuget

I just ran a Update-Package on a fresh asp mvc 4 project using the mobile template. Update-Package updates every nuget packages in the project and Web.Optimization did not get updated. After the update won't it render the css bundle when I use "Debug="false" in web config, though it worked before the update. Anyone have had simlar problems? I've done no changes to the code.

It works as it should when I set "Debug=true", but then it's not bundeling and minifying the css. When I load the page in a browser and open the developer tools (like firebug) can I still both find and view the minified css file. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appriciated.